# Sql Update statement issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying desperately to create a final table for a production envirnment, however Im having some issues....

I have 2 tables in my database.  MyTable has exactly the same format as the other (AnotherTable).  AnotherTable has the final value that I'd like to be in MyTable.

I am trying to update MyTable's gq value to equal the value in the AnotherTable's gq value.  I can no longer use AnotherTable in production, because it is archived data...

Thus my concern.  I wrote an update statement (below) that tries to do this.  The issue is that I don't want to update EVERY row of the MyTable each time that this update is called.  My 2nd where clause is throwing an "multipart identifier could not be bound" error.  Yet I need to have the 2nd where clause there in order to assure myself that I am not updating the entire database worth of information at once.

Please help!  I'm still feeling like a newb

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.gq= 
    (select top 1 ANotherTable.GQ as gq 
    from AnotherTable , MyTable
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), AnotherTable.UniqueTextField)= MyTable.uniqueVarCharField
    )
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), AnotherTable. UniqueTextField)
        = MyTable.uniqueVarCharField
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    M
SET
    MyTable.gq = A.gq
FROM
    MyTable M
    JOIN
    AnotherTable A ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), A.UniqueTextField)= M.uniqueVarCharField
```

The JOIN will restrict to where it matches.

However, you may need further filters in a WHERE clause or more JOIN conditions
This will still update every row where the tables intersect

Comment: Why does this select more rows than needed?  And how can I get it to only update the rows that I want it to?

Comment: You have to filter to the rows you want to update, not all matching rows. Example: do the tables have a common key?

Answer (score 0):

Your two tables just need a join:

```
UPDATE m SET m.Field = o.Field
FROM MyTable m INNER JOIN otherTable o ON m.JoinedField=o.JoinedField
```